# White powder on Tulasi leaves

Tags: plant-health

This white powdery layer on leaves is making too many leaves fall.
Please let me know what can be done to save it.

Comment: Give the plant a shower with dish soap, then spray with neem oil. No harm if soap falls on soil. Would you consider showing a picture of what you call **This whlte powdery layer**?

Comment: White powdery layer is normally some kind of mold (powdery mildew?).